# $product->getFinalPrice() and $product->isSaleable() are very slow when called from a product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection, product-collection

Loading around 400 products without using `$product->getFinalPrice()` and `$product->isSaleable()` usually takes around 2 seconds. When calling them, however, the load times shoot up to around 12 seconds.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$expandedCollection = array();      

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $price = $product->getPrice();      
        $specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();      

        $expandedCollection[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'price'      => $price,
            'specialprice'   => $specialPrice ,
            'visibility' => $product->getVisibility(),
            'short_description' => $product->getShortDescription(),
            'description' => $product->getDescription(),
            'eshopping_enabled' => (((int)$product->getStatus()) == 1 ? true : false),           
            'in_stock' => (bool) $product->isSaleable() ,
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),             
            'thumbnail_url' => $product->getThumbnailUrl()          
        );
    }
```

I assume this is caused because both these functions load the product stocks..

Is there any way to optimize the load times? Different server configuration, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about `getFinalPrice`, but getIsSalable() is loading all simple products for all configurable you are calling it on.

You can optimize it, by collecting all simple products and then implement this yourself.

```
private function getIsSalableFromData(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    $salable = $product->getStatus() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;

    if ($salable && $product->hasData('is_salable')) {
        return (bool) $product->getData('is_salable');
    }

    return $salable && !$product->isComposite();
}

$productData['is_salable'] = $this->getIsSalableFromData($product);
foreach ($simpleProducts as $simpleProduct) {
    $anySimpleProductIsAvailable = $anySimpleProductIsAvailable || $simpleProduct->isSalable();
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabian. Thank you for your input. I solved the issue a slightly different way. The problem was, it was loading the stock item for every single product individually. I added it as a join to the collection, so that it loads them all at once, along with addFinalPrice(), and that seemed to solve the issue. I'll accept your answer though in case someone needs your solution instead!