# Magento $_product->isSaleable() alternative

Tags: magento-1.9, stock-status

We have a Magento 1.9.3 site that only has configurable items on it.
On the list page, we need to check if the item is in stock, the way we're doing this is by checking `if($_product->isSaleable())` but in the `foreach` loop this is adding quite some load time (about .2 seconds per configurable item)

Is there a better way we can check if the item is in stock?
Because we're dealing with configurable items, what we're really trying to find out is if any of the children items are still in stock and thus the item is saleable.
If all the children items are out of stock the we just add a label that says `out of stock`

Comment: Please check this excellent answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86677/product-getfinalprice-and-product-issaleable-are-very-slow-when-called-f